# Return group of columns with highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called events. I need to return all the group of distinct rows with maximum value for time_of_event in a month. For example, if you take October 2018 as time of event, I need to return all the distinct group of rest of the columns who has the highest date in Oct 2018 for column time_of_event.
[image]

Comment: provide your desired output in table format

Comment: `SELECT user_id, date_joined,  time_of_event 
FROM events 
WHERE time_of_event  IN 
(
    SELECT MAX(time_of_event )
    FROM events
    GROUP BY YEAR(time_of_event ), MONTH(time_of_event )
)

group by user_id, date_joined,  time_of_event 
order by time_of_event  `

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The key thing is to identify the relevant time_of_event for each month. Then we can join that to the list to get all events.

To identify the latest time_of_event, you can use a group-by statement e.g.,

```
SELECT MAX(time_of_event) AS Last_time_of_event
FROM events_new
GROUP BY YEAR(time_of_event), MONTH(time_of_event)
```

The above provides a list of all the last date/time of the events. If you want to filter the result set, feel free to do so (e.g., add a `WHERE time_of_event >= '20180101' AND time_of_event < '20190101'`)

We can then use this as a sub-query or CTE to link to the original table to get all the events e.g.,

```
; WITH LTOE AS 
    (SELECT MAX(time_of_event) AS Last_time_of_event
    FROM events_new
    GROUP BY YEAR(time_of_event), MONTH(time_of_event)
    )
SELECT DISTINCT en.User_ID, en.Date_Joined, en.Time_of_event, en.Event
FROM   events_new en
       INNER JOIN LTOE on en.Last_time_of_event = en.time_of_event
```

(edit: fixed typo in GROUP BY and added DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DENSE_RANK` windowing function.  Something like this

```
with e_cte as (
    select *, dense_rank() over (partition by year(time_of_event), month(time_of_event) 
                                 order by time_of_event desc) dr
    from [events])
select distinct [user_id], date_joined, time_of_event
from e_cte
where dr=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just use window functions and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct en.*
from (select e.*, max(time_of_event) over () as max_time_of_event
      from events_new en
      where time_of_event >= '2018-10-01' and
            time_of_event < '2018-11-01'
     ) en
where time_of_event = max_time_of_event
```